# Pass multiple 'testURL' to jest in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a class in a react application which I'm unit testing with react. This class has methods that operate on the current url (parsing query params etc.). To be able to mock the url, I'm passing it as a config param like so

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --testURL=https://testurl.com?query=randomQuery"
```

This works fine but what I want to be able to do is pass multiple variations of the url to my test class to cover multiple conditions. For example, in addition to the above url, I might additionally want to pass something like

```
--testURL=https://testurl.com?somethingElse=randomQuery"
```

Is there a clean way to pass multiple instances of this to my test class. Possibly by declaring them within the test class itself?

Comment: It's not possible and wouldn't make much sense because there's no way to specify how multiple urls should be used. See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2460

Comment: @estus Thanks. When you say it wouldn't make much sense, does that mean needing the url the way I'm doing is odd? If yes, I'd be keen to understand what the best alternative is?

Comment: I mean that the framework wouldn't know how to use multiple urls even if it was possible to provide several of them. See Jest issue above. You likely need to get a reference to jsdom and use  jsdom.changeURL().